# htaccess Rewrite Error, Can not fetch $_GET value PHP :(

Tags: .htaccess

I am sorry to open a replicated question once again but I had no other choice. I am trying to write a clean URL using .htaccess. Here is my code:

```
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us about-us.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^careers careers.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us contact-us.php [NC,L]
```

these works very finely. but when I move on to URL's having some GET params like

```
example.com/providers.php?provider=huawei
```

and the htaccess rule goes as:

```
RewriteRule ^providers/([a-zA-Z_-]+)  providers.php?provider=$1 [NC,L]
```

When I navigate to the URL **example.com/providers/huawei** it throws an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: provider in directory\providers.php on line x
```

Appearantly, there is no error in the rule, I have gone through several video and StackOverflow solutions. Some suggested the use of **QSA** but no luck. I changed my production servers too still negative. Any help in this regard.

TIA

Comment: What is the URL you are you going to? Is it something like `/providers/foobar` ?

Comment: from example.com/providers.php?provider=huawei to xample.com/providers/huawei

Comment: Try adding this line to your htaccess `Options -MultiViews` . I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: still negative... no response

Comment: Okay, what happens if you change the pattern to `^providers/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$`  ? Do this change and don't remove the `multiviews` line I mentioned earlier.

Comment: let me check that too...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241639/discussion-between-asad-mehmood-and-amit-verma).